# Enable CDbCache and CDbCacheDependency

Tags: mysql, yii

I am trying to optimise a query by applying cache on it. But even after running the query again and again their is no change and no YiiCache table is created in my database. I think my CDbCache is not configured properly or dependency is not working. Or suggest something else to optimise SQL queries in Yii.

This my configuration :

```
    'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.caching.CDbCache',
        'connectionId'=>'db',
    ),
```

and i want to optimise this query:

```
    $dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(id) FROM         user_notification');

    $userNotificationModel = UserNotification::model()->cache(9000,            $dependency)->findAllByAttributes(
        array(
            'status' => NotificationCronCommand::QUEUED
        )
    );
```